# How to detect if someone uses a google analytics blocker?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

We have an online shop and we track the orders with google analytics. Some customers use an adblocker, some use googles official analytics blocker. How can I detect those at the checkout, so that I can pass a flag to my php script for this specific order?

Comment: Does this help:- http://support.buysellads.com/knowledge_base/topics/how-to-figure-out-what-percentage-of-your-visitors-are-using-an-ad-blocker

Comment: Welcome to the creepy zone. Adblocker you can check by checking against the visiblity of elements that you know it blocks. The analytics? Test for the iframe/script objects it makes after initialisation.

Comment: @RahulTripathi: The adblockers are not exactly my problem. Customers with adblocks dont block necessarily google analytics

Comment: @MichaelDibbets: The analytics object 'ga' is initialized even when I use the official blocker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Analytics use a cookie named _ga to track users.  If they have the Analytics Blocker extension enabled, it won't set that cookie, so you can just check if that cookie exists.